# I tried running code for my SLAMTECH RPlidar but the lidar doesnt get imported in my python window but it show it has been imported on my terminal

Tags: python-3.x, django, matplotlib, usb, lidar

Here is the error

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py", line 224, in process
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 959, in _start
    self._init_draw()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1703, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1726, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "/Users/lkhagvabyambajav/Desktop/rplidar/examples/animate.py", line 14, in update_line
    scan = next(iterator)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rplidar.py", line 357, in iter_scans
    for new_scan, quality, angle, distance in iterator:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rplidar.py", line 323, in iter_measurments
    raw = self._read_response(dsize)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rplidar.py", line 199, in _read_response
    raise RPLidarException('Wrong body size')
rplidar.RPLidarException: Wrong body size
```

and code is

```
from rplidar import RPLidar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
PORT_NAME = '/dev/tty.usbserial-0001'
DMAX = 4000
IMIN = 0
IMAX = 50
def update_line(num, iterator, line):
    scan = next(iterator)
    offsets = np.array([(np.radians(meas[1]), meas[2]) for meas in scan])
    line.set_offsets(offsets)
    intens = np.array([meas[0] for meas in scan])
    line.set_array(intens)
    return line,
def run():
    lidar = RPLidar(PORT_NAME)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    line = ax.scatter([0, 0], [0, 0], s=5, c=[IMIN, IMAX],
                           cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r, lw=0)
    ax.set_rmax(DMAX)
    ax.grid(True)
    iterator = lidar.iter_scans()
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_line,
        fargs=(iterator, line), interval=50)
    plt.show()
    lidar.stop()
    lidar.disconnect()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I didnt write this code it is from https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar
Im trying to test my lidar to see if it is working.
Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm using python 2.7 and Lidar A1M8 ('hardware': 7, 'model': 24, 'firmware': (1, 29)) to run it and it works with no errors.
So i think you should take a look at the RPlidar library and the lidar version which is supported, i've seen an issue about that constraint. Try to use another library like pylidar2.
there is the issue : https://github.com/SkoltechRobotics/rplidar/issues/36#issuecomment-787215840,
take a look at https://github.com/Roboticia/RPLidar